# Scala query to get number of tweets per user from JSON file

Tags: json, scala, twitter

I've collected tweets into a `JSON` formatted file. Now I am trying to print the number of tweets per user using scala code. I couldn't find any related info. on the internet. The thing I understood is to parse the `JSON` record using `gson` or `json4j` etc.., Part of the code is

```
val tweet = sqlContext.load("iphone6s.json", "json")
    tweet.printSchema()
    println(tweet.select("quoted_status.user.id_str").rdd)
    val userMap = tweet.map(x => (extractUserId(x), 1))
val numTweetsByUser = userMap.reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
```

In the above code, I've used a `regex` to extract the user id. But I would like to use key-value mapping of all fields so that I can perform some other queries.

Tweet schema is as follows

```
root
 |-- contributors: string (nullable = true)
 |-- coordinates: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- entities: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- hashtags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- media: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- display_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- expanded_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- media_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- media_url_https: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- sizes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- large: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- medium: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- small: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- thumb: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- source_status_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- source_status_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- source_user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- source_user_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- symbols: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- urls: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- display_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- expanded_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user_mentions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- extended_entities: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- media: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- display_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- expanded_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- media_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- media_url_https: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- sizes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- large: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- medium: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- small: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- thumb: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- source_status_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- source_status_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- source_user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- source_user_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- video_info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- aspect_ratio: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- duration_millis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- variants: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- bitrate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- content_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- favorite_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- favorited: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- filter_level: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- in_reply_to_screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- in_reply_to_status_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- in_reply_to_status_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- in_reply_to_user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- in_reply_to_user_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- is_quote_status: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |-- limit: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- timestamp_ms: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- track: long (nullable = true)
 |-- place: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bounding_box: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country_code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- full_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- place_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- possibly_sensitive: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- quoted_status: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- contributors: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- coordinates: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- created_at: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- entities: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- hashtags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- media: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- display_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- expanded_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- media_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- media_url_https: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- sizes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- large: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- medium: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- small: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- thumb: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- source_status_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- source_status_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- source_user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- source_user_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- symbols: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- urls: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- display_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- expanded_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- user_mentions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- extended_entities: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- media: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- display_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- expanded_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- indices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- media_url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- media_url_https: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- sizes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- large: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- medium: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- small: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- thumb: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- h: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- resize: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- w: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- source_status_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- source_status_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- source_user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- source_user_id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- video_info: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- aspect_ratio: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- duration_millis: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- variants: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- bitrate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- content_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you make your question more specific? You have the schema so you can do any SQL query you like, no?

Comment: Instead of SQL queries, I would like to use `map` and `reduceByKey` functions. What is the difference between SQL queries and `map`, `reduceByKey`?

Comment: Right now with Spark you have three options: (a) RDDs using functional programming with map, etc. (b) using DataFrames and the data frame API, and (c) using Spark SQL. All three can achieve the same things in slightly different expressions. It all comes dow to what comes more natural to you. If you a functional veteran, go with RDDs. If you a SQL analyst go with SQL. If you come from R and u like data frames, use DataFrames.